# How to change defaults in htmlize package?

Tags: htmlize

I installed the `htmlize` package but I want to change `htmlize-output-type: css`, (default) to  `htmlize-output-type: font` in the `html.el.html` file. https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize

Where do I find the `htmlize.el.html` file?

Comment: I changed the variabla with `C-h v` but it still has code coloring. Can I export to HTML without syntax coloring? I have a black & white printer.

Comment: `ps-print-buffer` solved the problem